Why is setting.name interpreted differently for same URL?
In my Flutter web app, when I navigate to: http://localhost:38431/?a=1#game, the router (MaterialApp.onGenerateRoute) gives me two RouteSettings.name for the same URL.
First it routes to "game", then to "/".
Why?
uri: http://localhost:38431/?a=1#game
settings.name: game
path: /
fragment: game
queryParams: {a: 1}
----------------
uri: http://localhost:38431/?a=1#game
settings.name: /      << ** Huh?  **
path: /
fragment: game
queryParams: {a: 1}
----------------

The following is the program I used to generate this?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_common/uiUtil/interaction.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Web Routing Example',
      // initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {

        final uri = Uri.parse(window.location.href);

        print("uri: ${uri}");
        print("settings.name: ${settings.name}");
        print("path: ${uri.path}");
        print("fragment: ${uri.fragment}");
        print("queryParams: ${uri.queryParameters}");
        print("----------------");

        final page = settings.name ?? "/";
        // print("page: ${page}");
        if (page == '/') {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage("Home"));
        } else if (page == '/game') {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage("Game"));
        } else if (page == '/settings') {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage("pwreset"));
        } else {
          // Handle other routes here
          return null;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage(this.title);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _paramA = '';
  String _paramB = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _extractParamsFromUrl();
  }

  void _extractParamsFromUrl() {
    final uri = Uri.parse(window.location.href);
    final queryParams = uri.queryParameters;

    setState(() {
      _paramA = queryParams['a'] ?? '';
      _paramB = queryParams['b'] ?? '';
      print("paramA:$_paramA, paramB:$_paramB");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Parameter A: $_paramA',
            ),
            Text(
              'Parameter B: $_paramB',
            ),
            tappableText(
                text: 'Go to Page 1',
                onTap: () {
                  _extractParamsFromUrl();
                  // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/page1');
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

